# Filter all Dataframe with values >= -1 & <= -1, and add that values to an another array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to know how to achieve this question. Given a dataframe, I want to create an array getting all values between -1 to 1, just the values, I don't care about the day or index.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
data = [[round(random.uniform(1,100),2) for i in range(7)] for i in range(10)]
header = [['Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves','Viernes', 'Sábado','Domingo']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = header)
mean = df.mean()
std = df.std()
df_normalizado = (df-mean)/std

      Lunes    Martes Miércoles    Jueves   Viernes    Sábado   Domingo
0 -0.250799  1.001706 -0.491738  0.444629 -0.296997 -0.670781 -1.554641
1 -0.868792 -0.100689 -0.359056  1.282681  1.352212  1.176829 -1.374482
2 -0.614918  1.187862  1.398010  1.037513 -1.149555 -0.834707  0.143520
3 -0.319758  1.113691 -0.719597 -1.392089 -0.591716  0.943564 -1.163994
4 -0.718137 -1.300041  1.267097 -0.797168  0.053323  1.187264  0.078008
5 -0.883286 -0.821076 -0.671478  1.268079  0.002583 -0.897651  1.096177
6  1.933040 -0.534570 -1.142057 -0.262689  1.417233  0.851335  0.780141
7 -0.433957 -0.575776  1.406855  0.248020 -1.113399 -0.178332  0.497165
8  1.357213 -1.070254 -0.882708 -1.133679 -0.863344 -1.613941  0.491402
9  0.799394  1.099147  0.194671 -0.695298  1.189661  0.036420  1.006704
```

To clarify:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK03b.png)

Thank you. community!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  You're simply filling a data frame with random values: this is a simple research problem, not a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Be precise. What do you want suppress or hide ? what is the result expected ? could you put your df code so that anyone could copy/paste it on its code editor ?

Comment: Thank you @LaurentB fro the advise. The post is updated with my code. I want a new array with just the values between -1 and 1 of the original dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since just an array is needed, grab [values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas-dataframe-values) from the DataFrame and use normal [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```py
a = df.values

print(a[(-1 <= a) & (a <= 1)])
```

Output:

```
[-0.250799 -0.491738  0.444629 -0.296997 -0.670781 -0.868792 -0.100689
 -0.359056 -0.614918 -0.834707  0.14352  -0.319758 -0.719597 -0.591716
  0.943564 -0.718137 -0.797168  0.053323  0.078008 -0.883286 -0.821076
 -0.671478  0.002583 -0.897651 -0.53457  -0.262689  0.851335  0.780141
 -0.433957 -0.575776  0.24802  -0.178332  0.497165 -0.882708 -0.863344
  0.491402  0.799394  0.194671 -0.695298  0.03642 ]
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why but in my df that returns an array of True-False values. Your output is my goal!

Comment: You passed the Boolean index back to `a` correct? It’s `a[boolean index]` where boolean index is `(-1 <= a) & (a <= 1)`

Comment: That's it, I didn't put the dataframe values in another variable. Thank you so much! @Henry Ecker

Answer (score 0):

Python pandas suggest query function.
I hope this would be helpful to slove your issue

```
df.query("Lunes >= -1 and Lunes <= 1 and 
          Martes >= -1 and Martes <= 1 and
          Miércoles >= -1 and Miércoles <= 1 and
          Jueves >= -1 and Jueves <= 1 and
          Viernes >= -1 and Viernes <= 1 and
          Sábado >= -1 and Sábado <= 1 and
          Domingo >= -1 and Domingo <=1")
```

Comment: Thank you! But it returns this for me: SyntaxError: Python keyword not valid identifier in numexpr query.